# Rails: validate unique combination of 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

leave_policy is table having columns :id ,:group_detail_id , employee_type_id,

I want to combination of :group_detail_id and employee_type_id should not be duplicate.

validates_uniqueness_of :employee_type_id ,:scope => :group_detail_id

this line is not working...I don't know why?????

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Is it returning an error ? Is it not behaving as expected ?

Comment: I got it..there were 2 models with the same name:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
validate :unique_combination

def unique_combination
  self.class.exists?(
    :employee_type_id => employee_type_id,
    :group_detail_id => group_detail_id
  )
end
```